# MYSQL FIND MOST FREQUENT(S) VALUES

Tags: mysql

I have the following query that correctly resolves the most frequent colour amongst rental cars. This works fine.

```
SELECT Colour
FROM car 
INNER JOIN rents
ON car.PlateNr=rents.PlateNr
GROUP BY car.colour
ORDER BY COUNT(car.colour) DESC
LIMIT 1
;
```

However if there are **2 equal most frequent values**(for car colour) the second one is lost. How can I select both most frequent values in MYSQL? I have seen in other DBMS the TOP 1 value option, but I dont seem to find the equivalent in MYSQL.

Comment: Please post some sample data and expected output. Also, what is your MySQL server version ? Can you upgrade to the latest version (8.0.2 and above) ?

Comment: @paulsm4 OP basically needs [`DENSE_RANK()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_dense-rank) functionality here. He is looking to get the top ranked row(s) [in case of ties, get them all].

Comment: Please try to avoid using ALL-CAPS as it's considered YELLING.

Comment: "I have seen in other DBMS the TOP 1 value option, but I dont seem to find the equivalent in MYSQL." Yes that's SQL Server you already are using it `TOP 1` in SQL server is the same as MySQL's `LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could calculate top colour count first and then use it to select records with the same value.

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c3cbbf/9).

```
SET @top_colour_cnt = (select COUNT(car.colour) as max_color_cnt
                       from car
                       GROUP BY car.colour
                       ORDER BY COUNT(car.colour) DESC
                       LIMIT 1
                      );

SELECT @top_colour_cnt;

SELECT Colour, COUNT(car.colour)
FROM car 
GROUP BY car.colour
having COUNT(car.colour) = @top_colour_cnt
;
```

Comment: It's possible to do the same with one query.. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c3cbbf/10